# System.out.println not outputting to console

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been using S.o.p to try and debug some code, and its not writing anything to the console. I thought that I just wasn't reaching the point in the code where I had it written, but I then added it to another piece of code where I knew for a fact was being executed. I have it in here:

```
  public MainMenuUI(MainMenuCntl theCreatingCntl) {
    theCreatingCntl = theMainMenuCntl;
    System.out.println("MMUIConstructor");
    initComponents();
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

The MainMenuUI pops up as expected, but the s.o.p does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner

Comment: We need more code!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your program with the `java` command instead of `javaw`. Here are the [differences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> The java command starts a Java application. It does this by starting a
>   Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and calling that
>   class's main method.
>
> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there
>   is no associated console window. Use javaw when you do not want a
>   command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however,
>   display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some
>   reason.

Comment: Is there some config option to set java as the default when running?

Comment: @user2966511 A better solution would be to use some kind file based logger. Generally when running a UI, you don't want to display the console window. You could run the command from the command line yourself instead

Comment: The GUI is currently in the design stage, so not having the console window is really hurting my ability to debug and find errors in my flow of control.